# Plot bar graph using matplot for nested dictionary with 10 labels

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I have 10 elements in inner_keys.
inner_keys = ['0-250ms', '250-500ms', '500-750ms', '750-1000ms', '1000-1250ms', '1250-1500ms', '1500-1750ms', '1750-2000ms', '2000-2250ms','>2250ms']

The nested dictionary to be plotted in bar graph is dictLatency
dictLatency = {'updateVirtualVolumeMetaData': {'0-250ms': 6, '250-500ms': 3, '750-1000ms': 1, '1000-1250ms': 1, '1250-1500ms': 1}, 'unbindAllVirtualVolumesFromHost': {'0-250ms': 1}, 'spaceStatsForVirtualVolume': {'0-250ms': 1, '250-500ms': 2, '500-750ms': 2, '750-1000ms': 1, '1250-1500ms': 2, '1500-1750ms': 1, '2000-2250ms': 1, '>2250ms': 49, '1750-2000ms': 2}, 'setStorageContainerContext': {'0-250ms': 4}, 'setContext': {'0-250ms': 1, '>2250ms': 30}, 'queryVirtualVolume': {'0-250ms': 510, '250-500ms': 265, '500-750ms': 76, '750-1000ms': 24, '1000-1250ms': 10, '1250-1500ms': 2, '1500-1750ms': 5, '1750-2000ms': 3, '>2250ms': 28}, 'queryArrays': {'0-250ms': 4}, 'queryVirtualVolumeInfo': {'0-250ms': 12, '250-500ms': 3, '750-1000ms': 2, '1000-1250ms': 1, '1500-1750ms': 1, '>2250ms': 4}, 'getEvents': {'0-250ms': 478, '250-500ms': 263, '500-750ms': 60, '750-1000ms': 19, '1000-1250ms': 9, '1250-1500ms': 3, '1500-1750ms': 3, '1750-2000ms': 2, '>2250ms': 46}, 'spaceStatsForStorageContainer': {'0-250ms': 93, '250-500ms': 18, '500-750ms': 6, '750-1000ms': 4, '1000-1250ms': 2, '1250-1500ms': 7, '1750-2000ms': 1, '>2250ms': 4}, 'setPEContext': {'0-250ms': 3, '250-500ms': 2, '500-750ms': 1, '750-1000ms': 1, '1250-1500ms': 1, '1750-2000ms': 1, '>2250ms': 3}, 'queryStorageContainer': {'0-250ms': 4}, 'bindVirtualVolume': {'0-250ms': 3}, 'createVirtualVolume': {'0-250ms': 3}, 'queryStorageContainerForArray': {'0-250ms': 4}, 'queryProtocolEndpoint': {'0-250ms': 2}, 'queryProtocolEndpointForArray': {'0-250ms': 2}, 'getTaskUpdate': {'0-250ms': 3, '1000-1250ms': 3, '>2250ms': 1}}

```
inner_keys = ['0-250ms', '250-500ms', '500-750ms', '750-1000ms', '1000-1250ms'
              '1250-1500ms', '1500-1750ms', '1750-2000ms', '2000-2250ms', '>2250ms']
colors = plt.cm.Set2.colors[:len(inner_keys)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 4))
for outerkey, innerdict in dictLatency.items():
    bottom = 0
    for innerkey, value in innerdict.items():
        ax.bar([outerkey], [value], bottom=bottom, color=colors[inner_keys.index(innerkey)])
        bottom += value
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
legend_handles = [Rectangle((0, 0), 0, 0, color=color, label=label) for color, label in 
                  zip(colors, inner_keys)]
ax.legend(handles=legend_handles)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
‘’’
```

I have 10 items in inner_keys while color expects only 9 items. So I am getting an exception
in this line (ax.bar([outerkey], [value], bottom=bottom, color=colors[inner_keys.index(innerkey)])). IndexError: tuple index out of range. I want to add one more unique color and get rid of the exception.

Comment: I updated the answer to your previous question. E.g., you can use `Set3` or `tab20` instead of `Set2`

Comment: Thank you. I used other options and it works. I have one more doubt. How to use barh plot instead of stacked bar graph. What modifications can I do to the above code to change from stacked bar graph to horizontal bar graph.

Comment: I edited the answer to the other question.

Comment: One more thing. plt.show() is showing a much better graph with nice resolution but plt.savefig(pathToGraph + '/Latency.jpg',  dpi=100,
                  bbox_inches = 'tight', orientation='landscape') is saving a graph which is not looking as good as plt.show(). What parameters should I use to get the resultant saved image as good as image from plt.show()?

Comment: You can try higher dpi. Like 200 or 300.